# Do irrelevant directions contribute to the IR dynamics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Is it not a misnomer to call in a non-perturbative setting an irrelevant direction irrelevant?
I know that it comes from perturbation theory where an irrelevant direction is irrelevant for the IR dynamics but in a non-perturbative regime an irrelevant direction should have effects in the IR.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerously_irrelevant_operator ?

Comment: @NiharKarve but I would say that every irrelevant operator that has a non-Gaussian fixed point should be important for the IR because they are IR attractive and hence should have the same value of the fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term “irrelevant direction” is still meaningful in a non-perturbative setting, but it has a different interpretation than in perturbation theory.

**In perturbation theory**, an irrelevant direction is one that does not affect the low-energy physics, because its coupling constant flows to zero as the energy scale decreases.

**In a non-perturbative setting**, an irrelevant direction is one that does not affect the existence and stability of a fixed point, because its eigenvalue is positive at the fixed point. This means that the coupling constant associated with an irrelevant direction can be chosen arbitrarily without changing the qualitative features of the renormalization group flow.

However, this does not mean that an irrelevant direction has no effects in the infrared (IR) regime. It just means that these effects are subleading compared to the effects of the relevant and marginal directions, which determine the universality class of the system. An irrelevant direction can still induce corrections to physical observables, such as critical exponents or correlation functions, but these corrections are typically suppressed by powers of the energy scale or the system size.

Comment: Thank you! But why are these corrections suppressed by powers of the energy scale?